# List of proper names?

Tags: text, filtering, classification, corpus

I'm trying to filter names out of text blobs. Currently I'm just generating a words list and filtering it by hand but I've got ~8k words to go so I'm looking for a better way. I could grab a dictionary and filter them out but that would cull names like smith and cliff.

What I need is either of the following:

- a list of common names (I'd need the >5k most common names)
- a list of names that also happen to be words

I figure between them, I can do a combined blacklist/whitelist to get what I need.

Comment: Common names in what language? Or in what country, because "Ali" is pretty popular in the US, despite being an Arabic name.

Comment: @John, As it happens, mostly, English but after that, just about anything. As to the "also words" bit; English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

US Census name list: http://www.census.gov/genealogy/www/

That should get you one angle on the problem, anyway.

***edited*** changed URL, per comment below about page moving. Nobody believes in HTTP 302 anymore?

Comment: the census might be a bit outdated and it also contains only frequent names so for example, Barak cannot be found in the male.first list and Obama cannot be found in the all.last file, even though the name Barak Obama is obviously rather common in written texts e.g. news sources, blogs, tweets etc.

Comment: That link to census.gov leads to a 404 now. It looks like this is the new top-level home of genealogy data on the Census site: http://www.census.gov/genealogy/www/.

Comment: This resource is offline during the government shutdown.  Any good alternatives?  Thank you.

Comment: the internet archive says, http://web.archive.org/web/20130929222430/https://www.census.gov/genealogy/www/

Comment: Here is the file location in 2020: https://www.census.gov/topics/population/genealogy.html (there is also a 2010 Census)

Answer (score 2):

From a post I found at [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Where-can-I-find-a-massive-list-of-English-proper-nouns):

> CMU's NELL project has collected a huge list of proper nouns from the web and categorized them by type. You can browse online at: [NELL KnowledgeBase Browser](http://rtw.ml.cmu.edu/rtw/kbbrowser/) and download the data at: [Resources & Data](http://rtw.ml.cmu.edu/rtw/resources).

Web scraping the results for, say, [personUS](http://rtw.ml.cmu.edu/rtw/kbbrowser/pred:personus) seems more efficient than what I did, which is extracting a list of names from phrases tagged as "person" in their big tab-delimited CSV file. Either way you'll be using regex.